# Api call gives error 500 on tRestClient on Talend and Insomnia but on Postman it gives 200 ok

Tags: postman, talend, insomnia

I'm pretty new to this topic so please bear with me.

I'm trying to call an api (a GET request) and on Postman it works fine - a bit slow but otherwise no issues. But when I try to call the same api using the tRestClient component on Talend (version 7.0.1) or using Insomnia, the api returns 500 error. It's the same call, with the same parameters and the same bearer token authentication.

Does anyone know why this happens? Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy ? Postman handles the system proxy, but it's not the case with Talend components

Comment: Try using tRest component

Comment: @IbrahimMezouar I'm not

Comment: @CleanBold doesn't work either

Comment: Then could you share the details of the call you're making ? It's hard to tell without actual code

Comment: @IbrahimMezouar unfortunately no I can't :( i would like to but I don't have permission to share the api. I get that without it the point of asking seems kind of moot, but i hoped that someone else had had a similar situation and knew what to do

Comment: I faced similar issue - Postman call was working fine and tRestClient call was returning 500 Internal Server Error. Two things fixed it - Using HTTPS instead of HTTP and by using tRest instead of tRestClient.